# Replace StartInfo.Filename user

Tags: c#, .net

I've been googleing for hours without any results.

I'm trying to open up a program that is located in `"C:\Users\myUsername\"` file, but I cannot find any way to replace MY username to other application-users.

```
firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Username?\AppData\Roaming\GameWool\Launcher.exe";
firstProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
firstProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

So, I'm basically trying to replace MY \Users\USERNAME. So, if someone is using the application, he's supposed to open the same "game" using their OWN \Users\Username.

I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Environment.UserName`, this will retrieve the current *username*

For some reasons, the path of the user's personnal folders may differs. You can instead use

```
var UserFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

But since you want to use `AppData\Roaming\`, this will directly lead you to that folder :

```
// C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
var UserRoamingFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

In your case, for the last example, the path will looks like this :

```
firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)}\GameWool\Launcher.exe"
```

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: you are welcome. You can accept my answer if it was helpful

Comment: I  replaced it with. -> 

``firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\"+ System.Environment.UserName +@"\AppData\``

Is that correct? I can accept in 10 minutes. :)

Comment: @Putte, you are welcome. you can use string interpolation. So it will look like: $@"C:\Users\{System.Environment.UserName}\AppData\"

Comment: I wouldn't build the `@"c:\Users\username"` path this way, the location of personnal folder may differs. @Polly do you mind if I edit your post to add more informations?

Comment: Oh nice! I just fixed that. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Cid, sure, you can do it

Comment: I added a bit more details. @Polly you're welcome :)

Comment: @Cid Can you please explain how I should do with the "StartInfo.FileName"? Really appreciated!